# Can I store a lua_State in shared memory?

Tags: c++, lua, shared-memory

I'm guessing not (or, if possible will almost certainly not be worth my time).

The way I'm thinking is to construct a mirror object that contain's `offset_ptr`'s that also sits in the class owns the `lua_State` that the child processes can use to obtain the locations of the relevant pointers to the state, whether or not that's feasible... there's also other objects that `lua_` methods would probably access that I'm not sure how I would pass them the correct addresses...

Guessing I would need a special allocator too, not sure if this is supported?

Comment: What's the goal here exactly? I didn't quite follow.

Comment: I have many objects that need to be processed (i.e. call an update method) and some worker processes that share the work of doing so between them. Some of these objects may want to call Lua scripts so they need the state saved somewhere. Currently I'm storing all the objects in a big block of shared memory, but the inclusion of a `lua_State` object is the first non-pod data structure (and first that I haven't created myself) I've had to deal with w/r/t the shared memory and it's raw pointer limitation.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean multiple workers could bang on the same `lua_State` at the same time? That'll likely cause problems unless you sync access to it using mutexes and semaphores etc.

Comment: Nah each object has their own `lua_State`. Each object is a self-contained lump of information and they are all processed in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Lua is implemented purely in standard C, allocating a `lua_State` in shared memory is clearly not supported out-of-the-box.  You could look at modifying the source to implement that functionality manually, but it probably wouldn't be worth the trouble.  Instead you should keep `lua_State`s out of shared memory, and just copy any important data into shared memory if necessary.

Comment: I don't know what is needed to allocate space in shared memory, but when you create a Lua state, you tell Lua what memory allocator to use. Perhaps this is enough.

Comment: @lhf, shared memory doesn't support raw pointers as they will be different addresses for each process. Boost includes an offset_ptr to fix this problem which is basically how far away that object is from the offset_ptr itself, this is portable across processes. Unfortunately as Lua is C it is heavy in it's pointer usage...